# Is 'seeing' after 'open to' a correct sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In a book that I'm reading, there is a sentence:

> We seem to be quite open `to seeing` others as people rather than coworkers or competitors.

I just wonder I should be `see` not `seeing` in the above sentence. Am I right? If no, what is the grammar point here?

Comment: _to seeing_ is right, although I am unaware of the grammar rule behind it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the "to" actually goes with "open."  The expression "open to" means willing to consider or do something. So in this case, "seeing others as people..." is what we are "open to."  "Seeing" in this case is a gerund, or verbal that functions as a noun.